# Online remount btrfs of root filesystem with different subvolume (snapshot)

Tags: mount, snapshot, btrfs

Let's say you have a btrfs root filesystem on an online system. You want to revert the filesystem to an earlier state, of which you have a snapshot:

`remount /dev/sdaX /  -o remount,subvol=snapshots/Y`

For the record, I've done this in a test system, and it does **not** work. The command returns with no errors, but the subvolume mounted is the same.

If this **did** work, what would be the consequences?
My guess is that open file descriptors would still point to the old subvolume, thus possibly leading to "data loss" on the new subvolume, if one was not careful.
Assuming one goes to the trouble of closing and reopening all open file descriptors, does this sound feasible? Or are there other types of problems?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible.  Even if you could manage to redirect all IO to the new subvolume, changing files out from under an application in the middle of accessing it would hopelessly corrupt the file and confuse the application.  If the file in question was a program, then it would cause the program to go haywire and only crash if you are lucky.

Comment: Wouldn't open file descriptors remain open? If that's the case, wouldn't the program still keep writing to the old subvolume? Obviously this wouldn't work if an application closes a file and reopens it shortly after, **expecting the contents to remain the same**, but don't think that's safe to assume in a sane program anyway?

Comment: @goncalopp, the whole point is to NOT keep open the existing files on the old subvol.

Comment: Indeed, thus one could, after remounting, restart daemons one by one, which would close the old FD and open new ones, which would point to the corresponding files on the new subvolume

Comment: For the purpose of reverting to an old snapshot, I don't see a problem doing it on-line: most files will remain the same (even backed by the same physical block), and for files that don't - yes, I expect the application holding the file to corrupt and crash. Obviously the required functionality for the mount command was not implemented but I still think it should.