# When rolling back a subvolume to a snapshot in btrfs, is simply renaming and keeping the old subvolume bad practice?

Tags: btrfs, snapshot, volume

I'm new to btrfs. I'm experimenting with snapshots and rollbacks. I read the answers here:

- [Conceptualizing btrfs - understanding snapshots, and space used](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209165/conceptualizing-btrfs-understanding-snapshots-and-space-used)
- [btrfs confused about subvolumes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134162/btrfs-confused-about-subvolumes)
- [Online remount btrfs of root filesystem with different subvolume (snapshot)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55421/online-remount-btrfs-of-root-filesystem-with-different-subvolume-snapshot)

I still don't get it.

My subvolid=0 is not mounted at boot. Instead, I have three subvolumes mounted at boot: `root`, `/home`, and `/.snapshots`. Suppose I created a snapshot of my root:

```
NOW=$(date +"snapshot-%d-%m-%y-%H-%M-%s")
btrfs subvolume snapshot / /.snapshots/$NOW
```

Then, I install some package (I'm on arch):

```
pacman -S vim
```

My system finds the installation disagreeable, so I want to rollback to the snapshot I made earlier.

```
opts=defaults,x-mount.mkdir,compress=lzo,ssd,noatime
sudo mount -t btrfs -o subvolid=0,$opts LABEL=system /mnt/btrfs-root
cd /mnt/btrfs-root
mv ./snapshots/$NOW ./rollback-root
mv ./root ./b4-$NOW-root
mv ./rollback-root ./root
cd
umount /mnt/btrfs-root
sudo reboot now
```

Doing so, I've successfully booted into the system that was running at snapshot time.

However, I now have a new subvolume, the discarded `/root` renamed as `b4-$NOW-root`.

If I mount my subvolid=0, and try to delete that subvolume, I get an error message.

Also, if I look into that mounted subvolume, I can see the `vim` package I installed in one of my bin directories.

It also seems that the bytes used by the file system has increased twice. Once after installation, which is expected, and then once again after I rolled back. Conceptually, I understand why this might be, but the fact that my filesystem bytes used increased twice seems to violate my semantic understanding of the phrase "roll back". Is there some best practice for rolling back in btrfs that, when rolled back, gets me to the original bytes used in the pre-installation system?

Comment: Do you use `subvolid` in the `rootflags` of your kernel cmdline?

Comment: No, I used ```root=UUID=xxxxxxxx=subvol=root```, which afaiu could be changed to reference instead the ```subvolid``` if that was somehow better...?